# Keep Foursquare "Places" in Facebook without publishing checkins in the newsfeed

Tags: facebook, geolocation, foursquare

Is it possible to keep the "Places" map in Facebook but not have every check-in in Foursquare published in the news feed? I find the map with all the check-ins interesting but I don't want to nag everybody with a status update of the places I visit.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your desire here. I don't know of a way to do these using the foursquare settings, however you might be able to hide the checkins using Facebook's privacy settings, or disabling Foursquare in your activity feed. Experiment and let us know.